# Comparing emperical var and means to theortical in R

Tags: python, r

I have and array "exp_v" with random numbers from exponential distribution and I want to compare the emperical mean and var to the theoretical ones.

My problem with my code is that I get only one value instead of getting 1000 different values.

This is my R code so far:

```
set.seed(3)
N = 1000
X = c()
u = runif(1000,0,1)

hist(u)

lambda = 1
formula = (-1/lambda)*log(1-u)

for (i in 0:N){
  exp_v = c(formula)
}

hist(exp_v)

realMean = lambda**-1
realVar = lambda**-2

mean_sim = c()
var_sim = c()
error_mean = c()
error_var = c()
for (i in 0:N){
  
  mean_sim = mean(exp_v)
  var_sim = var(exp_v)
  error_mean = abs(mean_sim - realMean)
  error_var = abs(var_sim - realVar)
  
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue with the codes you have written?

Comment: That I get only one value instead of getting 1000 different values

Comment: If you think the issue is with the R code only, you can delete the Python code. Also, can you clarify which variable should be a list with 1000 values? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: `exp_v` is an array and not a matrix.

Comment: You save only one value of your iterations. I think you should (for example) replace `mean_sim = mean(exp_v)` with `mean_sim[i] <- mean(exp_v)`. The same for all the other vectors used in your `for`-loops.

Comment: Also, start loops at 1.